# What is the best practice for updating related stores that may or may not be present?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the best practice for updating a store that may or may not exist? Where should the conditional check live? Here is my situation. I have a posts page and a post page. In redux, I have a posts slice of state that looks like this `posts: { 1: {…}, 2: {…} }`, `posts[1]` is used to store the posts for the posts page and `posts[2]` is used to store the post for the post page. Now, when I update a post on the post page (`post[2]`) I also need to update that post in the posts page (`post[1]`). I don’t refetch the `posts[1]` when I travel back. The goal is that a user can travel from page to page and leave off where they started. The problem is that, if a user loads the post page before the posts page - the `posts[1]` store doesn’t contain the appropriate post to update. What is the best way someone could layout these type of conditional updates so that no matter what is or isn't in the store could be updated as needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just dispatch a `POST_UPDATED` action with the details of the post update.  Add one or more reducers that listen to that action and apply the update to their section of the store.

For example, your `posts` store can listen to the action and update the entry in `posts` if it has been loaded.  Your `post` store can *also* listen to the action and update the single post in its store.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I understand what you are saying and use such code in most places. The problem is more complex. Sorry for not explaining this better. I have ```posts[1]: {allIds: [...], byId: {...}}```. It's a normalized structure. If I load the post page directly there are no posts in ```posts[1]``` so when I update a post in ```posts[2]``` it tries to look it up by id in ```posts[1]``` and errors. I can do a check like against the store for the post in ```post[1]``` in my component and then update it but is that the best way to accomplish this? Thanks!